# Is there any way to declare queries as variables and use them per row in PostgreSql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a report with specific columns that needs to be calculated.
How can I declare variables and use them in main query?
**the x, y and z are different for each of row**

```
x = (select sum(...) from... where...)::numeric
y = (select sum(...) from... where...)::numeric
z = (select sum(...) from... where...)::numeric

select
id,
client.first_name as first_name,
client.last_name as last_name,
...
...
...
x as x_amount,
y as y_amount,
z as z_amount,
(x+y+z) - z * 11.4/100 as amount_1,
x - y + z * 2.5/100 as amount_2,
x + y + z as amount_3,
...
from
...
where
...
```

```
So this need to give me result like bellow()
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
first_name|last_name |...|amount_1|amount_2|amount3|...
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    name1 |last_name1|...|  12.4. |  15.7  |  48.5 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    name2 |last_name1|...|  30.1  |  45.9   | 78.2 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    name3 |last_name3|...|  50.6  |  75.9   | 99.3 |
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)

```
with x_var as (
  select sum(...)::numeric as x
  from... 
  where...
), y_var as (
  select sum(...)::numeric as y
  from... 
  where...
), z_var as (
  select sum(...)::numeric as z
  from... 
  where...
)
select id,
       cl.first_name,
       cl.last_name,
       ...
       ...
       ...
       x as x_amount,
       y as y_amount,
       z as z_amount,
       (x+y+z) - z * 11.4/100 as amount_1,
       x - y + z * 2.5/100 as amount_2,
       x + y + z as amount_3,
       ...
from client cl
  cross join x_var
  cross join y_var
  cross join z_var
where ...
```

This assumes that your queries for the "variables" return exactly one row